# how to convert a Flux<Object> list into a List<Object>

Tags: java-8, java-stream, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

I have a Flux and I want to convert it to List. How can I do that?

```java
Flux<Object> getInstances(String serviceId); // Current one 
List<Object> getInstances(String serviceId); // Demanded one
```

Java 8 or reactive components have a prepared method to map or convert it to List ??

I should use `.map()`

```java
final List<ServiceInstance> sis = convertedStringList.parallelStream()
            .map( this.reactiveDiscoveryClient::getInstances )
            // It should be converted to List<Object>
```

Answer (score 9):

#### 1. Make sure you want this

A fair warning before diving into anything else: Converting a `Flux` to a `List`/`Stream` makes the whole thing **not reactive** in the strict sense of the concept because you are leaving the push domain and trading it with a pull domain. You may or may not want this (usually you don't) depending on the use-case. Just wanted to leave the note.

#### 2. Converting a Flux to a List

According to the [Flux documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--), the `collectList` method will return a `Mono<List<T>>`. It will return immediately, but it's not the resulting list itself, but a lazy structure, the `Mono`, that promises the result will eventually be there when the sequence is completed.

According to the [Mono documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--), the `block` method will return the contents of the Mono when it completes. Keep in mind that `block` may return null.

Combining both, you could use `someFlux.collectList().block()`. Provided that `someFlux` is a `Flux<Object>`, the result would be a `List<Object>`.

The `block` method won't return anything if the Flux is infinite. As an example, the following will return a list with two words:

```java
Flux.fromArray(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}).collectList().block()
```

But the following will never return:

```java
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).collectList().block()
```

To prevent blocking indefinitely or for too long, you may pass a `Duration` argument to `block`, but that will timeout with an exception when the subscription does not complete on time.

#### 3. Converting a Flux to a Stream

According to the [Flux documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#toStream--), the `toStream` method converts a `Flux<T>` into a `Stream<T>`. This is more friendly to operators such as `flatMap`. Mind this simple example, for the sake of demonstration:

```
Stream.of("f")
    .flatMap(letter ->
                Flux.fromArray(new String[]{"foo", "bar"})
                        .filter(word -> word.startsWith(letter)).toStream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

One could simply use `.collectList().block().stream()`, but not only it's less readable, but it could also result in NPE if `block` returned null. This approach does not finish for an infinite Flux as well, but because this is a stream of unknown size, you can still use some operations on it before it's complete, without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert Project Reactor Flux into java.util.List without blocking the thread and terminate async process, you can do it this way

```
Flux.fromIterable("Str1","Str2","Str3") //Flux<String>
    .collectList() //Mono<List<String>>
    .flatMap(listStrs -> {Do whatever you want with the list})
```

The key function is `collectionList()` that gather all result into single `Mono<List<String>>`

**Note**: `collectionList()` does not block the thread BUT introduces a form of "wait" to collect all the elements from the previous operation and return them into a list

Java Doc
[image: collectionListDesc]